# bash on pi3B+ stretch; shell script to fork ' program &' --bash cannot find file. It IS there

Tags: bash, shell-script

Have tried variations with/without ' and &, spelling full path, adding to $PATH.  The script cannot seem to find hyperping, tho it is in the same directory as the script which is calling it.  Executing as user pi.  Pulling my hair OUT!!
Actual line in script

```
if [ $(/usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping) -eq 0 ]; then './hyperping &'; fi
```

"hyperping" is in PATH [verified via $PATH, also via removing &]

```
***pi@pi20:~/tests $ ls -lt hyperping
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 692 Jul 30 13:10 hyperping***
```

"hyperping" runs fine called independently.

output of bash with "set -xv"

```
***/++ /usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ '/home/pi/tests/hyperping &'
./at7PM: line 33: /home/pi/tests/hyperping &: *No such file or
directory*/****
```

Comment: Kusalananda's answer is absolutely correct, that command would tell the shell to run a program literally called `hyperping &`. But, if your problem is with the script blocking, then what happens after that command is also relevant. What is it that actually gets blocked? Also, what happens if you put something like `sleep 1234 & echo hi > /tmp/hello.txt` there? Can you see the `sleep` in `ps`, and does the file get created before the sleep finishes? If yes, then running the command in the background is not the problem.

Comment: Also, it's obvious that the error message you show isn't from the code you show. The command clearly says `'./hyperping &'`, while the error says `/home/pi/tests/hyperping &`. Now, perhaps you only changed the path, but in general, there's no way for the reader to know if that was the _only_ change you made. Since we can't see your actual code, it falls to you to provide the correct details, including matching code and output.

Answer (score 4):

You're not running `hyperping`, you are attempting to run a command called `hyperping &` (literally, with space and `&`).  This happens because you are needlessly quoting the command `./hyperping &` as `'./hyperping &'`.

I'm assuming that you are intending to do something like

```bsh
if ! pgrep hyperping >/dev/null; then
    hyperping &
fi
```

If your `pgrep` has a `-q` option to make it quiet, then you may drop the `>/dev/null`:

```bsh
if ! pgrep -q hyperping; then
    hyperping &
fi
```

The `pgrep` command acts a bit like `grep` in that it exits with a zero exit status if it successfully finds the thing that you are looking for, and otherwise exits with a non-zero exit status.  We may use that as shown above to avoid having to parse the actual *output* of the command for clues about whether it found something or not.  You may read `if ! pgrep somecommand; then ...; fi` as "if there's not a command called `somecommand` running, then ...".

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  I have tried many variations.  The if does pass and it tries to execute.  So I tried without the "&" and I get the same thing. ++ /usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ ' /home/pi/tests/hyperping '
./at10AM: line 33:  /home/pi/tests/hyperping : No such file or directory

Comment: @JohnLoop I'm assuming that you are still quoting `hyperping ` (with a space at the end)?  Don't quote the command name at all. Doing that makes the space part of the command's name.

Comment: I tried your syntax but nothing passed "bash -n"     pi@pi20:~/tests $ bash -n at10AM
at10AM: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
at10AM: line 34: ` if ! /usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping; then ./hyperping &; fi'

at10AM: line 34: ` if ! (/usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping); then ./hyperping &; fi'

at10AM: line 34: ` if ! $(/usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping); then ./hyperping &; fi'

at10AM: line 34: ` if ! [ $(/usr/bin/pgrep -c hyperping) ]; then ./hyperping &; fi'

Comment: @JohnLoop Seriously, read your code.  What is `at10AM` doing in there?  Also, read _my_ code. I'm not using `pgrep -c` at all.

Comment: The at10AM is the whole script that contains the line I am referencing.  It runs fine.  Here is the last thing I tried.        pi@pi20:~/tests $ bash -n at10AM
at10AM: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
at10AM: line 34: ` if ! pgrep -c hyperping; then ./hyperping &; fi'

Comment: @JohnLoop I wish that you try my code as I wrote it. Had I written it on a single line I would have written `if pgrep hyperping >/dev/null; then hyperping & fi`.  Note the lack of `;` after `&`.  Both `&` and `;` are command terminators, and you can't use both.  Consider spacing your code out on several lines though, to make it readable and understandable.  Lines of text are free.

Comment: Your code works great [thanks for alt script], but it doesn't fork "hyperping"  -- I changed the single --hyperping &-- to -- "./hyperping &"-- and it still can't find file.   I thot bash could fork a script...... + pgrep -c hyperping
0
+ './hyperping &'
./at10AM: line 35: ./hyperping &: No such file or directory

Comment: @JohnLoop Again, _don't_ quote the command. The issue is rather that `hyperping` isn't in your `PATH`.  If `hypeping` is in the current directory, then use `./hyperping &` (no quotes at all!).  If it's located elsewhere, then use the full absolute path to the command.

Comment: I give up for now.  When I don't quote it, it WILL execute it [finds it], but it executes inline, blocking the rest of the code until it finishes.   I want it to execute separately.  I think I will change script to allow inline execution!  I can do that with a few changes.  Thanks for input.  Why won't bash fork?

Comment: @JohnLoop If you add `&` at the end, it _will_ start `hyperspin` in the background.  Since I don't see your full script, or know how you determine that it's not working, I can't  say much more.

Answer (score -1):

SELECT is not broken!

> Have tried variations with/without ' and &, spelling full path, adding
> to $PATH.

Kusalamanda already pointed out the error of adding quotes around your command by random, enclosing a blank and the ampersand - don't do that. There are too many crazy ideas, to test them all out.

Quotes in bash and similar shells don't work as in most other programming languages. Their main purpose is, to preserve blanks and other whitespace characters. Unfortunately, a lot of developers subconsciously import their syntax habits from other languages, and act as if every string needs quotes.

> The script cannot seem to find hyperping, tho it is in the same directory as the script which is calling it.

That is absolutely irrelevant, and maybe a second error, interfering with your first one.

An executable is found because it either is in the path, then you have to call it without providing a path.

Or it is not in the path, then you have to provide a relative path (like ./some/where/script.sh) or the absolute path. Relative paths are considered relative to the position, from where the caller (you in your shell) is calling them, not relative to another script/program, by which they are called indirectly.

If your script is in the path, don't call it with a relative path like `./hyperping`, but just `hyperping`, because if it is called with a relative path, the path will not be used to find it, and it will depend on the position, from where it is called, which is in general a bad idea.

Comment: It has no problem finding the script without the quotes, but it blocks the script it is embedded in.  I wanted it to fork [hence putting it in 's, maybe not correct?, maybe backticks are needed], but giving up for now and adjusting to let it run inline.  Thanks for comments.

Comment: You append an ampersand (after whitespace), to run a script, program or command non blocking (=in the background). You don't use backticks for this purpose - they are used, but deprecated, to capture the output of a prg/cmd/script. `today=$(date)` but is blocking too. And if the program is found, then by accident, because you started it from the same directory, not because the calling script is in the same directory.